# Problema con resultados de un Scraping en python con beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Estoy empezando con Python.

Quiero sacar unos datos de una web.

Me he estado documentando pero me esta costando. Bueno el caso es que recupero la información que necesito, porque lo veo en el for que recorre el array pero después no soy capaz de trabajar con esa posición en la variable.

El código es:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "http://www.morningstar.es/es/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F0GBR04AR1"

# Realizamos la petición a la web
req = requests.get(URL)

# Comprobamos que la petición nos devuelve un Status Code = 200
status_code = req.status_code
if status_code == 200:

    # Pasamos el contenido HTML de la web a un objeto BeautifulSoup()
    html = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "html.parser")

    # Obtenemos todos los divs donde están las entradas
    entradas = html.find_all('td', {'class': 'line text'})

    print(entradas[2])
    for i, entrada in enumerate(entradas):
        print (i, entrada)

    print('---')
    print(entradas[0])

    #no funciona la siguiente linea
    type(entradas)

    valor_antes = entradas[0]
    print(valor_antes)

    #no funciona las siguientes lineas
    type(valor_antes)
    len(valor_antes)



else:
    print ("Error: Status Code %d" % status_code)
```

Y el resultado es:

```
    <td class="line text">LU0011850392</td>
0 <td class="line text">EUR 115,83</td>
1 <td class="line text">-0,32%
                      </td>
2 <td class="line text">LU0011850392</td>
3 <td class="line text">EUR 808,94</td>
4 <td class="line text">EUR 685,22</td>
5 <td class="line text">5,00%
          </td>
6 <td class="line text">2,25%</td>
---
<td class="line text">EUR 115,83</td>
<td class="line text">EUR 115,83</td>
[Finished in 2.2s]
```

Como podéis ver el type o el len no muestran nada. He intentado acrotala y alguna cosa mas pero no me sale.

Creo que entradas[] no es un array.

Alguna ayuda?

Muchísimas gracias

Comment: `entrada` es una instancia de `bs4.element.ResultSet`, no te muestra el tipo ni el número de items porque **simplemente no  imprimes la salida** de las funciones (`print(type(entradas)`) y `print(len(entradas)`). Ten en cuenta que no estás ejecutando la línea en un intérprete interactivo... Y si es iterables e  indizable, `entradas[0]` te retorna el primer item. Aunque no es una lista si a eso te refieres con "array", si quieres una lista puedes hacer simplemente `entradas_list = list(entradas)`, aunque no creo que necesites esto para nada.

Comment: Hola, FJSevilla, muchas gracias pero creo que no me explique bien.

Lo que necesito es, al final, tener una variable que pueda usar con este valor: 115,83. Lo tengo que sacar de forma automática y no soy capaz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres tener una lista con los elementos de la tabla puedes hacer algo como esto:

Seguramente publiquen una respuesta mejor, pero humildemente, yo lo haría asi.

Obtener la tabla a traves de su clase:

```
tabla = html.find_all(class_='snapshotTextColor snapshotTextFontStyle snapshotTable overviewKeyStatsTable')
```

De esta manera buscamos todos los tags `td`, si quieres puedes hacerlo de la forma tradicional :

```
contenido = [i.get_text(strip=True) for i in tabla[0].find_all('td')]
```

Como la lista muestra algunos elementos vacios, `('')`, de esta manera solo tomamos los que no lo son.

```
contenido = [ item for item in contenido if item != '']
```

y tu output seria asi:

```
['Estadística Rápida',
 'VL30/07/2019',
 'EUR\xa0115,83',
 'Cambio del día',
 '-0,32%',
 'Categoría Morningstar™',
 'RV Europa Emergente',
 'ISIN',
 'LU0011850392',
 'Patrimonio (Mil)28/06/2019',
 'EUR\xa0808,94',
 'Patrimonio Clase (Mil)30/07/2019',
 'EUR\xa0682,51',
 'Comisión Máx. Suscripción',
 '5,00%',
 'Gastos Corrientes25/02/2019',
 '2,25%']
```

Y si los `\xa0` son problema, los podemos reemplazar o sino con `unicodedata` los normalizamos:

```
import unicodedata
contenido = [unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", item) for item in contenido]
```

y ahora tu output es asi:

```
['Estadística Rápida',
 'VL30/07/2019',
 'EUR 115,83',
 'Cambio del día',
 '-0,32%',
 'Categoría MorningstarTM',
 'RV Europa Emergente',
 'ISIN',
 'LU0011850392',
 'Patrimonio (Mil)28/06/2019',
 'EUR 808,94',
 'Patrimonio Clase (Mil)30/07/2019',
 'EUR 682,51',
 'Comisión Máx. Suscripción',
 '5,00%',
 'Gastos Corrientes25/02/2019',
 '2,25%']
```

y puedes acceder a cualquier elemento con `contenido[n]`

y si realmente deseas trabajarlo como valor númerico, podemos jugar con una `regex`, de la siguiente manera:

```
contenido[2] 
>>
'EUR 115,83'
```

Y nuestro objetivo sería pasarlo a un valor númerico, o sea un tipo de dato `float`

```
import re

x = re.compile(r"([\d,\.]+)").findall(contenido[2])

# x es ahora una lista de un elemento que contiene `['115,83']`    
# entonces podemos acceder al primer elemento [0] y reemplazar la 'coma' por un 'punto'.

x = x[0].replace(',','.')
#y finalmente se puede castear     
    x = float(x)
#output:
print(x)
>>115.83
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda, saludos

Comment: Luchas perfecto. Muchísimas gracias.

Ya puedo hacer rico :-)))

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es imprimir el tipo o el tamaño en consola, tienes que utilizar el método `print`

En tu caso sería

```py
    print(type(entradas))

    valor_antes = entradas[0]
    print(valor_antes)


    print(type(valor_antes))
    print(len(valor_antes))
```

Comment: Vale, si, tienes razón pero no me deja trabajar con esa variable.

Lo que quiero es que sea un valor numero de 115,83